# Python Windows throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex

This is head sample of my file:

```
1.1.1.0 - 1.1.1.255
2.2.2.0 - 2.2.2.255
3.3.3.0 - 3.3.3.100
```

This is my Python regex code:

```
regex = r'(?P<start>\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.\w+) \- (?P<end>\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.\w+)'
with open('sorted_french_ips.txt', 'r') as file:
    with open('sorted_french_edited_ips.txt', 'a') as sorted_french_edited_ips:
        for line in file:
            find = re.match(regex, line)
            start = find.group('start')
            end = find.group('end')
            cidr = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(start, end)
            cidr = str(cidr)
            cidr = cidr.replace(', IPNetwork', '\n')
            cidr = cidr.replace('[IPNetwork(\'', '')
            cidr = cidr.replace('\')]', '')
            cidr = cidr.replace('(\'', '')
            cidr = cidr.replace('\')', '')
            sorted_french_edited_ips.write(f'{cidr}\n')
```

When I run this code in Windows, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\python-projects\win.py", line 131, in <module>
    write()
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\python-projects\win.py", line 81, in write
    start = find.group('start')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

But if I run the same code in Linux, it works fine.

Why I get error in Windows? Are Window's regex and Linux different? Should it be changed?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the input file is the same on both computers?

Comment: Which Python version is used?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Windows: Python 3.9.12. Linux server: Python 3.8.10. WSL: Python 3.8.10.

Comment: @JohnGordon, no they are not the same. Output file in Linux should be converted from CRLF to LF to work. But only additional command in Linux is `dos2unix file.py`.

Comment: you should try without the dos2unix conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input text file is Unicode encoded with a byte order mark, BOM. When you open the file in Python in Windows, by default, the system encoding is used, which is different from Unicode, and the BOM byte sequence is read in as part of the text.

The [`re.match` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only finds a match if the match occurs at the start of the string.

The first `line` does not start with the pattern you defined, it starts with the BOM sequence.

To fix the problem, make sure you read the file with the right encoding.

If your file is UTF-8 BOM encoded, use

```py
with open('sorted_french_ips.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
```

In Linux, *usually*, the default encoding is UTF-8 without BOM, hence it works without setting the `encoding` argument explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I was not home to test and say thanks. Thanks, my file's encoding is `utf-16` and I replaced with your answer's encoding and it worked:) In fact, it is `UTF-16, little-endian` as per `file file.txt`'s output and `utf-16` worked.